# Font edit markerclustering

Tags: leaflet, markerclusterer, leaflet.markercluster

is it possible to edit only the font and its size on leaflet marker cluster? without changing the main icon?

In that case where I would have to put the line?

```
var clusterGroup = L.markerClusterGroup();
{

function estiloIcon(feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {
        icon: myIcon
    })
};
var geojsonLayer = new L.geoJson(geo, {
    pointToLayer: estiloIcon

})

clusterGroup.addLayer(geojsonLayer); 
}
map.addLayer(clusterGroup);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I already found the answer lookin in the archives of "MasterCluster.Default.css" In the bottom of the file there is the lines to modify the font

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'freesans'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('./freesansbold.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}
.marker-cluster {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 20px;
    }
.marker-cluster div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;

    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font: 16px "freesans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #fff, -2px 0 0 #fff, 0 2px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 0 #fff, 1px 1px #fff, -1px -1px 0 #fff, 1px -1px 0 #fff, -1px 1px 0 #fff;
    }
```

This is the lines edited